# Adding DataAnnotation Validation to Internal Property

Tags: c#, data-annotations

Is it possible to validate an internal property which has a data annotation?

For example:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Required, Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    internal int CustomerID { get; set; }
}
```

When validating using

```
Validator.TryValidateObject(customerInstance, new ValidationContext(customerInstance), null, true);
```

It is not validating the internal field.. I'm assuming this is because the "`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`" assembly knows nothing about the internals of my assembly.

I had tried making the DataAnnotation assembly a "Friend" assembly with the following statement before my Customer class:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, PublicKey=0024000004.....")]
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

The reason for me making the CustomerID internal is that nothing outside of my assembly should need to know about it.